# Most compatible/supported I2C based touchscreen to emulate?

Tags: touchscreen, driver, input-device

Without going into boring details, I need to get a touchscreen input into a Raspberry Pi which will be "faked" by a microcontroller - so the micro is reading some input and translating it to a touch coordinate and passing it to the Pi.

This means I want to choose a well-supported and hopefully not too complicated touchscreen device to emulate in the micro so that I don't have to modify the standard Raspberry Pi OS with extra drivers etc. any more than is absolutely necessary.

It doesn't need anything more than single-touch capability if that helps, but it must be I2C based.

Comment: Pretty sure touchscreens are standardized for USB (ie., generally made to fulfill a generic public protocol).  So chances are all you have to do is make something that also fulfills it (no need for reverse engineering).

Comment: It's not USB though, it's through I2C interface.

Comment: Dunno if there is a generic standard for that.  There are a bunch of drivers for them in the kernel source though, `grep -i i2c [src]/drivers/input/touchscreen` should get them.  Take your pick...

Comment: What *I2C based* touch screens have you found so far @JohnU?

Answer (score 2):

There are many touschscreens for the Pi that use an I2C interface.

Pimoroni's [HyperPixel](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/hyperpixel-4?variant=12569539706963) uses a FocalTech FT6236. [Datasheet for the controller.](https://focuslcds.com/content/FT6236.pdf)

AdaFruit's [PiTFT 2.8"](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2423) uses a FocalTech FT6206.

Both of these are capactive multi-touch, and use drivers that are already in the Raspberry Pi OS. Check out the [DTS file](https://github.com/pimoroni/hyperpixel4/blob/pi4/src/hyperpixel4-overlay.dts) to see which driver is used, how it is configured etc.